# Nested templates vs shift operator

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, bit-shift

I have been reading all around about be aware `>>` as ending of nested template and `>>` as shift operator...

Now I have tried it in my MSVS2010 and no problem occured.

`std::map<int, std::pair<int, int>> m;`

This code works exactly what I want (map of pairs) but I supposed to get some error about `>>`

Compiler is smarter these days?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MSVC++2010 supports C++0x feature [Right Angle Brackets](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#brackets)

Answer (score 9):

Be careful because previously good C++03 code may break with compilers supporting this feature.

```
MyArray< MyArray<int, 16 >> 2>, 5 > arrayInst;
```

This would be the fix:

```
MyArray< MyArray<int, (16 >> 2)>, 5 > arrayInst;
```

Comment: We all would have been better off had they used `(T)` instead of `<T>` in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

> This code works exactly what I want (map of pairs) but I supposed to get some error about >>

C++0x has fixed this. So if you're not getting any error with MSVS2010, then its no wonder, as MSVS2010 has implemented some of C++0x features.

Also, even with C++03, many compilers handle such cases, though not required by the Standard(2003).

Comment: Actually, it's not allowed for a conforming C++03 compiler to implement C++0x semantics for `>>`. There are valid C++03 constructs which can break with this change.

Comment: @Charles: Interesting. But I would like to know what valid C++03 constructs can be broken with this change, and how C++0x handles this then?

Comment: @Nawaz: E.g. shift expressions in constant expressions for non-type template parameters. E.g. `tmpl< tmpl<2 >> 1> > instance;`. Usually valid C++03 becomes a compile error in C++0x. I haven't managed to construct any situation where this causes a silent change in behaviour.

Comment: @Charles: How does C++0x handle this then? Is it going to interpret `>>` in `<2 >> 1>` as shift operator?

Comment: @Nawaz: As I indicated, it's a compile error. `>>` closes the template, leaving a non-sensical `1> > instance;` token sequence where a declarator is needed.

Comment: @Charles: In other words, I can say that few valid C++03 things are invalid in C++0x, right?

Comment: @Nawaz: I'm not 100% sure I know what you are driving. Are you looking to make a wider generalisation? There are **a** few things that are valid C++03 and aren't valid C++0x. Not least there are several more keywords that can no long be used as ordinary identifiers.

Comment: @Charles: *Are you looking to make a wider generalisation?*... what does it mean? Are we discussing some philosophy? :-/

Comment: @Nawaz: You said "I can say that few valid C++03 things are invalid in C++0x, right?", my thoughts were that you could say that but we really only touched on one corner case and there a probable many others.

Answer (score 3):

[C++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Right_angle_bracket) now supports that syntax without errors.  Compilers have already started to implement most of these features, so it wouldn't be surprising that the latest Microsoft C++ compiler supports it.