# Template issue with vector

Tags: c++, vector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [For nested templates, when did `>>` become standard C++ (instead of `> >`)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087033/for-nested-templates-when-did-become-standard-c-instead-of)
>   [Why did templates of templates (e.g. vector<vector<int> >) require a space between the closing angle brackets prior to C++0x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087166/why-did-templates-of-templates-e-g-vectorvectorint-require-a-space-betwe)

I am simply trying to create a vector:

```
vector<Transform3D<double>> tempVector;
```

This is the compilation error i get:

```
/../main.cpp:34:26: error: a space is required between consecutive right angle brackets
  (use '> >')
vector<Transform3D<double>> tempVector;
                         ^~
                         > >
```

What does not make is sense is, why the problem is solved by changing the vector to as the error describes:

```
vector<Transform3D<double > > tempVector;
```

Why is `vector<Transform3D<double>>` and `vector<Transform3D<double > >` not identical?

Comment: Prior to C++11, the `>>` would likely confuse the compiler as being the `>>` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They aren't identical (at least prior to C++11) because the last `>>` characters are parsed as a single operator (`operator>>`). Putting a space between them causes the expected behavior.

The same situation happens where the compiler parses `<:` as the beginning of a tigraph/digraph. For example:

```
N<::T> // <: parsed as [
```

A space separating the operators causes the code to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Because `>>` is a bit shift operator, a newer compiler can distinguish the two though.