# Failure while trying to construct a std::list with an allocator

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, stl

I have found a strange behaviour while trying to complie some code with plain std::list taking a custom allocator. Consider the following code:

```
std::list<int, std::allocator<int>> theList;
theList.push_back(1);
```

It's a normal list variable with some data being added. Now if I switch it to:

```
std::list<int, std::allocator<int>> theList(std::allocator<int>());
theList.push_back(1);
```

Visual Studio 2012 fails to compile it with "error C2228: left of '.push_back' must have class/struct/union". Of course std::list has a constructor which takes a const reference to an allocator. But if i change it to:

```
std::list<int, std::allocator<int>> theList = std::list<int, std::allocator<int>>(std::allocator<int>());
theList.push_back(1);
```

all is fine. Why is the second part failing? To add to the strangeness of the situation, when trying to return theList by value:

```
typedef std::list<int, std::allocator<int>> TempType;

TempType func()
{
    TempType theList(std::allocator<int>());
    return theList;
}
```

I get "error C2664: 'std::list<_Ty,_Alloc>::list(const std::list<_Ty,*Alloc> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'TempType (*_cdecl *)(std::allocator<*Ty> (*_cdecl *)(void))' to 'const std::list<_Ty,_Alloc> &'". Looks like the compiler treats the list as a function declaration. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: isnt list supposed to be of one T, not two?

Comment: @Infested std::list can take an allocator as the second type

Comment: I assume that in your real code, `std::list<int, std::allocator<int>>` is actually written as `std::list<int, std::allocator<int> >`? (I've not looked more in-depth; not very experienced with allocators)

Comment: @Dave actually the exact code I posted gives the same errors, so the actual types are irrelevant. The interesting part is that I get the same bahaviour with std::unordered_set.

Comment: @Dave: neither needed nor relevant.

Comment: @PlasmaHH actually it is needed for C++ pre-C++11: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7087054/1180785 (although I wasn't aware until now that they'd fixed it in the new standard). If you had different behaviour, it was because your compiler was being nice, but your code was non-portable.

Comment: Can we have a bot which identifies the most vexing parse, and variants thereof? Should I ask that on meta?

Comment: @Dave: I have "different behaviour", because I work with compilers supporting the /current/ C++ standards as good as they can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have run into [the most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). The compiler is parsing the definition of `theList(std::allocator<int>())` as a function declaration. This should fix you up:

```
std::allocator<int> alloc;
std::list<int, std::allocator> > theList(alloc);
```

Comment: @GManNickG - `std::list` does not have a constructor that takes an rvalue reference, so passing `move(alloc)` will call the lvalue constructor, so there's no difference.

Comment: @PeteBecker: You're right, my fault. I was a bit surprised at first, but it makes sense since the allocator is almost certainly just going to be `rebind`ed.

Answer (score 3):

It's known as [the most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

You accidentally declared a *function*.  Adding an extra set of parenthesis will make it unambiguous.

```
std::list<int, std::allocator<int>> theList((std::allocator<int>()));
//                                          ^                     ^
```

Comment: but, why wouldnt it go to the constructor that gets that type? i mean, int i(0) is equal to int i = 0

Comment: @Infested: note how int(0) and int() are different, now throw in a name and you have "int f()" which is.. well, what is it?