# How to define a vector of two dimensional array?

Tags: c++

How to define a vector that will contain two-dimensional arrays.

eg: `vector<array[16][16]> vec;` // where the two dimensional array have string elements

which will contain `vec ={array_1[16][16],array_2[16][16],array_3[16][16],....};`

---

I have tried:

```
vector<array<array<string,16>,16>> vec;
```

but it does not work when I use `vec.push_back(array);`

error shown is:

> No matching member function for call to 'push_back'

minimal code:

```
string arr[16][16];

vector<array<array<string,16>,16>> vec;

vec.push_back(arr);
```

Comment: what does `does not work.` mean? Didn't compile? What was the error message? Please provide a [mre], your code [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/c8nEcP)

Comment: std::vector<std::vector<int>> v;

Comment: let me add the error too and update the question

Comment: @Kao if `std::array` is supported the compiler should be c++11 compliant and accept the angle brackets without spaces: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087033/for-nested-templates-when-did-become-standard-c-instead-of

Comment: You can't name a variable like a type. You are shadowing `std::array`. You should rename it and use `std::array` instead of C-arrays: `string array[16][16];` => `array<array<string,16>,16> arr;`

Comment: Your `string array[16][16];` is not a `std::array`

Comment: @Damien so making in `array<array<string,16>,16>` should do the job?

Comment: @AdithyaShetty I guess yes. Pay attention to the name of the variable, not `array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't name a variable like a type. You are shadowing `std::array`. You should rename the variable and use `std::array` instead of C-arrays:

```
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using StrArr2D = std::array<std::array<std::string, 16>, 16>;

int main() {
    StrArr2D arr;
    std::vector<StrArr2D> vec;
    vec.push_back(arr);
}
```

You can keep the variable name `array` if you avoid `using namespace std;` and use full qualified names.

Comment: i am getting a as  error `Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::array<std::array<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, 16>, 16>'` when I tried the above

Comment: Why not just use `arr` as the variable name? Like you use `vec` for the `vector` variable.  Then you don't have to worry about the `using namespace std` issue.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The variable name was `array` earlier. I wanted to show different ways. But now, after OP changed the code in the question, it makes no sense to call the array `array`.

Comment: @ThomasSablik In your example, I would add a `using` declaration to make the code earlier to read, eg: `using StrArr2D = std::array<std::string, 16>, 16>; StrArr2D arr; std::vector<StrArr2D> vec; ...`